# Invalid credential in Login page shows success after testing JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I have my recording script in JMeter.In login page I have 7 users that need to be log in..I created 7 wrong passwords and 7 wrong usernames inside csv file..It shows success after running...How to validate the usernames and passwords in JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful. If your application responds to incorrect login with [`200 OK`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) status JMeter will consider the request passed.

You can add custom pass/fail criteria to your JMeter test using [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), for example you can add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) which will expect i.e. `Welcome, ${username}` text presence or absence of login form elements or whatever way of indicating user is being logged in is available.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally failing JMeter samplers using Assertions.